# equivalant of fprint in c++

Tags: c++, io, stderr

`g++ (GCC) 4.6.0 20110419 (Red Hat 4.6.0-5`)

what is the equivalent of this in c++? I know that this will compile in g++. But I just interested to see if there is any thing else in c++ that I can use like this.

```
fprintf(stderr, "Server failed to receive message [ %s ]\n", stderror(errno));
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about:

```
std::cerr << "Server failed to receive message [" << stderror(errno)) << "]" << std::endl;
```

Comment: @Macmade: Perfectly right how? `std::endl` is no more or no less platform dependent than `\n`.

Comment: The difference is that std::endl flushes the buffer.

Comment: @Macmade: `std::cerr` flushes after every output operation anyway, though.

Comment: Right... But that's not the case of std::cout... So better to use std::endl in any case...

Comment: @Macmade, I deleted my comment just before I found out. However, good for someone else who might what that information about the headers. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [cerr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cerr/) in [iostream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/iostream/). Its like cout, but for stderr.

```
 #include <iostream>

 std::cerr << "Server failed to receive message [ " << stderror(errno) << " ]" 
           << std::endl;
```

Or you can use [boost::forma](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/format/index.html)t to get a type safe sprintf.

```
 using namespace boost;
 std::cerr 
   << format("Server failed to receive message [ %s ]") % stderror(errno)
   << std::endl;
```

Comment: +1 for `boost::format`. You can dump a `format` object directly to the stream. You don't need the call to `str()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the output stream cerr.

`cerr << "Server failed to receive message [ " << stderror(errno) << " ]" << endl;`

Comment: I believe `endl` flushes the buffer, which would be a useful thing for an error message. That makes this answer better than one which uses `\n`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: `cerr` flushes after each output operation (by default) anyway so the only difference between `\n` and `std::endl` doesn't matter here anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A more general answer: you can use any istream object with the stream operators. There are a lot of other types of objects that inherit from istream. For example, fstream objects are a type of istream used for file I/O. There's also sstream (string stream) objects which are used in a similar way to sprintf and sscanf.

That being said, I'd be wary of using the C++ stream operators instead of the C equivalents (which are also supported in C++.) If you use the C++ ones, [it's going to make internationalization very difficult.](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/web-vs-c++.html#misfeature-4)